# amazon aws-amplify react js

Tags: amazon-s3

I am new in aws i am using aws-amplify to upload file on amazon s3 and its work but the uploaded content is save in the bucket public folder so how to make it private and second thing when i get the file i got the file url through which i can download the file but i only want the content url i dont want to download it i just want the link of my file.  any one please help me 
i have follow this link 
https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/storage_guide

Answer (score 0):

When you perform the upload, you are setting the level of protection option, like so?

```
Storage.put('test.txt', 'Protected Content', {
    level: 'protected',
    contentType: 'text/plain'
})
```

Comment: yes i have tried with the protected also with the private but its not worked for me